# Cannot get current user from session in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-oauth, passport.js

I am facing a terrible problem. I am making an app with Google auth functionality. All is done. When I login with Google I am successfully setting a session in my browser's cookie but the problem is I cannot get current user by making request from react but I can get current user from browser

// If I visit this from browser I can get current user

```
https://localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/success
```

//but the same not work when I make request with react

```
const fetchUser = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      "https://localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/success"
    );
    console.log(data);
    try {
    } catch (err) {}
  }
```

Someone please solve my problem if you want I can show you my code via any way.

Comment: in the catch block, please console.log the error to check what went wrong and update the question

Comment: the request do not failed I can see the response but user is empty  {
"user": "101794848524050318901"
} this is response if I request with browser . but from react response is {}

Comment: do you access any other routes in browser before the one from the question?

Comment: yes all works just fine

Comment: no, I mean, you posted in the question the `success` route and my guerss is that you do a login before. If so, your browser is storing some data as cookies/session used for the request you mentioned (that data is decoded and that's why you are able to get data from breowser. But if you try from your server, but you do not store any of the data from previous requests, then you don't send anything to be decoded, so you don't get any user

Comment: in browser when I hit login route I redirect to google login page and then session successfully saved in cookie. I am attaching the cookie from browser to express middleware with passport.desrialize this also work fine .. now If visit any of the route of the server I should see req.user but it work only for the browser not from react even though I am using same browser